# PHP function to check for banned words

Tags: php, function

I have this function to check for banned words in my string. However, I cannot detect banned words if the spaces are removed - rendering the function useless. Can someone help me improve it to detect the words without spaces.

```
$string = "Hellomynameisuser.";
check_for_banned_words($string);

function check_for_banned_words($string){
    $badWords = array(
        "ban",
        "bad",
        "user",
        "pass",
        "stack",
        "name",
        "html"
    );
    $matches = array();
    $matchFound = preg_match_all(
        "/\b(" . implode($badWords,"|") . ")\b/i", 
        $string, 
        $matches
    );
    if($matchFound):
        $words = array_unique($matches[0]);
        echo("<ul>");
        foreach($words as $word):
            echo("<li>" . $word . "</li>");
        endforeach;
        echo("</ul>");
    endif;
}
```

Comment: [clbuttic](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html) question!

Comment: If you do that, however, you are going to also forbid words such as "banana" and "namely". Is that what you want?

Comment: @DanFromGermany or what we used to refer to as the *Scunthorpe* problem where I worked in the early days of really bad profanity filters ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\b` detects word boundaries, remove them to get a regular match.

```
"/(" . implode("|", $badWords) . ")/i",
```